# Interpretation of Quantum Fourier transform

Tags: quantum-information, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement

Hadamard converts a qubit into an Equal superposition of its basis states

But

What does A Quantum fourier transform do to the ste of the qubit, could anyone explain to me the fundamental interpretation of it?

Please explain wrt these examples

[image]

how a 3 qubit system transforms according to QFT
[image]

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363333/2451

Comment: Yes I made this one more concise and direct so that it clearly states my query and what information I need, because I think that is what possibly the previous question lacked, which possibly could be the reason for no possible   answer to it

Answer (score 1):

The Hadamard transform is the two dimensional quantum Fourier transform.  Doing a Hadamard transform on two bits in parallel is different from the quantum Fourier transform, though.  The QFT on two bits is, as a matrix, proportional to

```
1  1  1  1
1  i -1 -i
1 -1  1 -1
1 -i -1  i
```

whereas two Hadamards in parallel are proportional to

```
1  1  1  1
1 -1  1 -1
1  1 -1 -1
1 -1 -1  1.
```

The difference can be thought of as arranging the four states in a line for the QFT and in a square for the Hadamard.  That is, the four states are

```
|x> = |0>, |1>, |2>, |3>
```

for the QFT but

```
|x,y> = |0,0>, |0,1>, |1,0>, |1,1>
```

for the two Hadamards.  In the QFT, the phase changes by 1^(1/4) = i as x increases, whereas in the Hadamard matrix, it changes by 1^(1/2) = -1 as either of x or y increase.